# How to get battery optimization permission result after asking permission?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to give `isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations` to my app.

And I know that how to check if app has isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations permission or not, and if not, the way of asking permission.

That is below code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val powerManager = this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
            if (!powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {

                val intent = Intent().apply {
                    action = Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS
                    data = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
                    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                }

                this.startActivity(intent)
            } else {
            
            }
        }
```

So it successfully show the notification to ask the permission of ignoring batter optimization.

And this notification has two button, 'no authorization' and 'authorization'.

User will click one of them.

Then How to get that result?

I only can find asking-permission code, but can't find get result of permission.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's a [section in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) on requesting permissions at runtime - it has a full workflow for checking if you have a permission, setting up the request if you don't, and then handling the result of that request.

You have two options [outlined here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#request-permission), either let the system handle it, or write your own code to wrangle the request and its response - letting the system do it is what's recommended. You basically just create the callback object (which checks if the permission was granted or not and acts accordingly), and then `launch` it with the relevant permission constant.

```
// set up the callback
val requestPermissionLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(RequestPermission()) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
           ...
        } else {
           ...
        }
    }


// fire off the request when required
requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.REQUESTED_PERMISSION)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called `BatteryPermissionHelper` that might help you. You can check it out here: https://github.com/WaseemSabir/BatteryPermissionHelper.

Can be used like this:

```
dependencies {
    // ... other dependencies
    implementation 'com.waseemsabir:betterypermissionhelper:1.0.0'    
}
```

```
private val batteryPermissionHelper = BatteryPermissionHelper.getInstance()

// check whether or not Battery Permission is Available for Device
val isBatteryPermissionAvailable = batteryPermissionHelper.isBatterySaverPermissionAvailable(context = context, onlyIfSupported = true)

// Show a dialog based on availability (Implementation left to Dev) and OnClick open permission manager
dialog.setOnClickListener {
    batteryPermissionHelper.getPermission(this, open = true, newTask = true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to find out whether the user granted the permission, you have to check the isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations status again after you know the user has returned to your app.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val powerManager = this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        if (powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
            // The app has the "Ignore Battery Optimizations" permission
        } else {
            // The app does not have the "Ignore Battery Optimizations" permission
        }
    }
}
```